# AngularJS with JSF/Primefaces fails in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, primefaces

I have put together an AngularJS application served up with JSF/primefaces. This page works just fine if brought up with Chrome or IE, but if brought up in Firefox, it does not perform AngularJS expansions. So when I looked at the JS console, I get the following error on the first line of my JS script (reservation_list.js):

```
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

All this line contains is:

```
var disJockeySpyModule = angular.module('ReservationList', []);
```

I think there is a problem with the ordering or locations of my  elements that is peculiar to Firefox.  I've tried rearranging the order and location of  elements to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

My XHTML file is below (modified to protect the proprietary nature of actual content):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head />

<h:body>
  <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
      <h:form id="myForm">
        <div ng-app="ReservationList">
          <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
          <script
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
          <h:outputScript library="js" name="reservation_list.js" />
          <div ng-controller="myController">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div
                      class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                      <div
                        class="ui-panel-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
                        <span class="ui-panel-title">#{messages._reservation_list}</span>
                      </div>
                      <ul class="reservation-list">
                        <li class="reservation"
                          ng-repeat="(key, reservation) in reservations"
                          ng-click="setCurrentReservation(reservation)"
                          title="#{messages.reservation_id} {{reservation.id}}">
                          <table>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td><label class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">{{reservation.reservationId}}</label></td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </h:form>
    </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Download angualr.js into your resources folder and include it via outputScript with a `target="header"`.

Comment: Thank you - that solves it! Unfortunately I didn't see your response until after I had already figured it out. I put fuller description below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem - and the explanation may be particular to my network environment (which accesses the internet through a proxy).

In our environment, when we access HTTPS sites for the first time, Firefox presents us with the following dialog warning us about an untrusted connection - perhaps the certificates cannot be accessed through our proxy (not sure exactly):

> This Connection is Untrusted
>
> You have asked Firefox to connect
>   securely to ajax.googleapis.com
>
> Normally, when you try to connect
>   securely, sites will present trusted identification to prove that you
>   are going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be
>   verified.
>
> What Should I Do?
>
> If you usually connect to this site without problems, this error could
>   mean that someone is trying to impersonate the site, and you shouldn't
>   continue.

Evidently Firefox is blocking the page from downloading AngularJS at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js

I got the same Firefox dialog when I type the AngularJS URL directly in the address bar. Once I add the exception, my page works fine in Firefox. This of course is not an acceptable solution for other users with the same network configuration, because they will never figure this out. So my final solution was to download AngularJS and include it in my JSF .war file as a javascript resource.